# If $f(x)=x^3+x^2+ax+4\sin x$ is increasing for all real values of $x$, find the interval in which the variable $a$ lies.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry, maxima-minima

I have this problem

*If $f(x)=x^3+x^2+ax+4\sin x$ is increasing for all real values of $x$, then $a$ lies in the interval*

So what I did was to first differentiate the function and equate it to greater than equal to zero ie

$f'(x)=3x^2+2x+a+4\cos x \geq 0$

I also know that the determinant of this value should be less than 0.
But I don't know what to do after this. I asked my teacher and some other sources and they just substituted $\cos x=-1$ and wrote the equation as : 
$f'(x)=3x^2+2x+a-4 \geq 0$

I don't know what to do after this and why did my teacher do so. If you can guide me then it would be great.

Comment: Well, you said it yourself: The determinant should be negative. So, go ahead and calculate the determinant :)

Comment: But there is this cosx term which creating issues. I don't know how to eliminate it and according to the solution that I have it should be eliminated before finding the determinant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show why the idea of "just replace $\cos(x)$ with it's smallest value $-1$" doesn't give you the whole range of $a$, look at the following picture, that plots both the actual derivative $f'(x)=3x^2+2x+a+4\cos(x)$ in red and the "replacement" $r(x)=3x^2+2x+a-4$ in black, for $a=0$:

[image: f'(x) and replacement]

$r(x)$ is negative for some $x$ around $0$, and that's why Devansh Kamra's solution says $a$ should be at least $\frac{13}3$. But as can be seen, the actual derivative (in red) is not negative anywhere. So $a=0$ is a valid choice for $a$, that Devansh Kamra's solution ignores.

The reason this is so is that "just replace $\cos(x)$ with it's smallest value $-1$" is conservative: You can see in the picture that the red plot is always above the black plot, which is easy to understand because the difference between those 2 functions is $4\cos(x)+4$, which is $\ge 0$. Devansh Kamra's solution correctly finds exactly all $a$ where the replacement function $r(x)$ is non-negative. This in turn makes sure that the actual derivative $f'(x)$ is also non-negative, so we are now sure that for all $a \ge \frac{13}3$ $f'(x)$ is non-negative.

But we can't make the reverse conclusion, we don't know if more $a$ exist. Because we assumed "the worst case" for $\cos(x)$ (that it is $-1$), we are missing $a=0$, where around $x=0$ $\cos(x)$ is near $1$, so the $+4\cos(x)$-term is "actively helping" to keep  $f'(x)$ above $0$.

---

So how to find the actual range of $a$ such that $f'(x) \ge 0$?

We have $f'(x)=3x^2+2x+a+4\cos(x)$, so $a$ is just an added constant.

If we find the minumum value of $g(x)=3x^2+2x+4\cos(x)$, we have found the maximal possible $-a$.

So we have $g'(x)=6x+2-4\sin(x), g''(x)=6-4\cos(x)>0$. $g(x)$ is dominated by the quadratic term $3x^2$ for large $|x|$ and $g''$ is always positive, so
solving $g'(x)=0$ will find the $x$-value where $g(x)$ becomes minimal.

As can be seen here, there is exactly one solution:

[image: linear vs. sinus]

I don't think there is a way to find the solution explicitely, a common fix-point iteration would be

$$x_0=-0.8, x_{n+1}=\frac{2\sin(x_n)-1}3$$

and this leads to the solution $x_s \approx -0.82140...$ and $g(x_s)\approx 3.106...$

This means that the interval for $a$ where $f'(x)$ is always non-negative is

$$a \ge -g(x_s) \approx -3.106...,$$

where $x_s$ is the only real solution to $6x+2=4\sin(x)$,  $x_s \approx -0.82140...$.

Comment: your answer was awesome. This thing just blew my mind. Thanks a lot for your help and by the way you just proved the answer in my book to be wrong ;)

Comment: The other idea is not bad, it gives you something to start with. But it should me clearly understood that you "miss something". Sometimes it turns out the real solution is the same. Sometimes it turns out the real solution is "very near" the approximation. Here it turns out the approximation say $ a \ge 4.3333\ldots$ but the real solution is $a \ge -3.106...$, which is IMO a moderate difference. It you can't solve the part after the "-----", that is not bad, it's not simple. But it is important to understand that there is still something to solve.

Comment: u are a great teacher. Thanks a lot for your efforts and time. A big thanks for putting so much hardwork.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f'(x)=3x^2+2x+a+4\cos x$ consists of two functions, $g(x)=3x^2+2x+a$ and $h(x)=4\cos x$
$$g'(x)= 6x+2$$
equating that to $0$, we get:
$$x=\dfrac{-1}{3}$$
which means the minimum value of $g(x)$ will be at $x=\dfrac{-1}{3}$
$$g_{min}(x)=g(\dfrac{-1}{3})=\dfrac{3a-1}{3}$$
The minimum value of $h(x)$(for any value of $x$, not necessarily $\dfrac{-1}{3}$) is $-4$

$\therefore$ if $\dfrac{3a-1}{3}-4\geq 0$, then for all values of $x$, $f'(x)\geq 0$
$$\dfrac{3a-1}{3}-4\geq 0$$
$$a\geq \dfrac{13}{3}$$

Comment: Wow...this is a really cool way to solve this. Thanks a lot @DevanshKamra :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that the minimum value of the cosine term is $-1.$ Thus, if the function $f'$ is to be positive for all real $x,$ then we must consider the least value the function can take, and choose $a$ so that this value is positive. Hence the setting of $\cos x=-1.$

Comment: Ohh...this was so simple and I didn't think about this at all . Thanks a lot @Allawonder

Comment: Note that this is a conservative appraoch. It makes sure that all $a$ you get this way actually fulfill the condition. But you might miss an $a$ where $3x^2+2x+a-4$ is negative in a small intervall $(x_0,x_1)$, but $\cos(x)$ is far from $-1$ in this interval, so the actual derivative $3x^2+2x+a+4\cos(x)$ is never negative.