Find the values of $b$ for which $f(x)=x^3+bx^2+3x+\sin(x)$ is bijective

Find the values of $b$ for which $f(x)=x^3+bx^2+3x+\sin(x)$ is bijective.

As we know $f(x)$ is surjective, the only task left to prove it bijective is to prove that $f(x)$  is strictly monotonic (which is equivalent to proving it injective because it's already continuous), which means that the derivative shouldn't change sign, and also that the derivative is non-zero except at isolated points.
My attempt:
So I tried to prove that derivative is either fully negative and fully positive for all values of $x$.
$$f'(x) = 3x^2+2bx+3+\cos(x)$$
I graphed the derivative on desmos and figured out that $f'(x)$ can't be negative for all values of $x$ but it can be positive for all values of $x$ between an interval of $b$ values, which from the graph comes out to be $[-3.2,3.2]$
Thus the original question can be reduced to for what values of $b$ is $f'(x)$ positive for all $x$ values, i.e. the graph lies above the $x$-axis.
I got the answer from the graph but I can't solve the question to the answer. I tried just randomly with discriminant but it is pointless as the derivative of the function is not a polynomial obviously.

I might have used the words postive and negative a bit more vaguely (including points at which it is 0) because as the derivative is zero only at distinct points, it is of no issue.

Since $\cos x$ takes all values in $[-1,1]$, the only way to have $f'(x)$ of constant sign for all $x\in\mathbb R$ is either if $3x^2 + 2bx +3\ge 1$ for all $x$, or $3x^2 + 2bx + 3\le -1$ for all $x$. So you just need to solve these two inequations for $b$

Try to determine the minimum of $f'(x)$.

@Stratossupportsthestrike What you wrote is not entirely correct. It's a way to find values of $x$ where $f'(x)$ is guaranteed to be one sign, but you may miss values. For example, your approach would say that $x^2+\cos(x)$ can only be positive for $|x| \ge 1$, which is not true (its value at $x=0$ is $1$, for example). If $3x^2+2bx+3$ is in $(-1,1)$, you cannot say without knowing $x$ if the additional $\cos(x)$ term can change the sign. For the OP, I don't think there is a closed forum solution for the 'complete' condition $3x^2+2bx+3+\cos(x) \ge 0$.

@Stratossupportsthestrike $3x^2+2bx+3\le -1$ cannot hold for all values of $x.$

@PaulFrost  It it had been just the quadratic I've done it lol :) I'm unsure about the cos x

@Ingix I also think the same......but still if we could reach to the approximations

I think using graphical tools is the best you can do. I answered a similar question some time ago on this site https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3634388/if-fx-x3x2ax4-sin-x-is-increasing-for-all-real-values-of-x-find-the/3634611#3634611 (sorry, I don't have much time now to do something similar for your question).
